# How to reset the field value on a custom form field?

Tags: jira

I have a custom field in Jira and I want to set the value on the field to match the current user.

This seems as though it should be fairly easy, but it has stumped me. I have trawled for information and have been led to using post functions.

Post functions don't seem to actually pre-set the value of fields on the create issue screen unfortunately? I am able to set a value which appears on the issue once it is created using a post function but I cant seem to find a way to set the value on the form itself.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you want the field to have value that matches current user, wouldn't it be enough just to use reporter/assignee field ?

Comment: Hi ThePavolC, the field itself has a specific use beyond reporter/assignee and so cant be done as part of one of those values.

Comment: @rfkortekaas when removing tags from questions during burnination, please be sure to fix *all* problems with the question.

Comment: @TylerH I will pay more attention to it!

Answer (score 0):

There is [Default Values for 'Create Issue' screen](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.gebsun.plugins.jira.defaultvalues) plugin which seems to be doing exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this plugin does not seem to allow for dynamic data such as current_user?

It would also be ideal to find a solution that isn't reliant on a third party paid app. I am very grateful for the advice but it seems as though using post functions or something similar I could achieve the result?

Comment: Post functions are linked with changes in already existing issues so I doubt it is possible with that.